# How to generate liquibase changelog with insert statement?

Tags: java, database, liquibase

I'm getting my hands on the Liquibase tool and I'd like to mimic working with an existing database. From the command line, I managed to generate the changelog. I was wondering whether it's possible to generate insert statements for data insides the tables?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes.  Use the --diffTypes="data" parameter output CSV files that are referenced from the generated changelog and will populate your database.

Comment: Something like `mvn liquibase:generateChangeLog -Dliquibase.diffTypes=data`